# How to get file name with extension from oleObject of Excel file using aspose?

Tags: java, excel, ole, aspose-cells

I am trying to get the file name of the ole object from excel file using aspose cells.
For majority of files I am able to get it using getSourceFullName().
I even tried other methods related to file name.
In specific cases, I get null for getSourceFullName(); but the binary data is still there and I can create a file for it if I know the extn.

This is my code snippet:

```
// Loop through all the ole objects and extract each object. in the worksheet.
        for (int i = 0; i < oles.getCount(); i++) {
            if (oles.get(i).getMsoDrawingType() == MsoDrawingType.OLE_OBJECT) {
                OleObject ole = (OleObject) oles.get(i);

                String sRow=""+ole.getActualLowerRightRow();
                //Cell cells = workbook.getWorksheets().get(0).getCells().getCell(ole.getActualLowerRightRow(), 26);
                //System.out.println(ole.getPlacement());
                //System.out.println(ole.getLinkedCell());
                String sOrgFile=ole.getSourceFullName();

                //System.out.println(   ole.getZOrderPosition());
                //System.out.println(ole.getId());
                if(sOrgFile == null) //This code is only skipping those file with null resourceFullNme. 
                {
                    continue;//this is to handle the issue that resoirceFull name is NULL for certain embedded file.
                }


                String sFnamme= new File(sOrgFile).getName();
```

I get every other information  except file name.
Can someone please help me through this?

Thanks in advance.
-Swapnil

Comment: Please try our latest version of Aspose.Cells (https://products.aspose.com/cells/java) and use newer OleObject.getObjectSourceFullName() method for your requirements.

If you still find any issue, we recommend you to kindly post your issue with attachments @ forums (https://forum.aspose.com/c/cells).

PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: I am using aspose-cells-20.3.jar

Comment: did you try using latest version (Aspose.Cells for Java v20.8)? If not, please do it using OleObject.getObjectSourceFullName() method.

Comment: yes. I tried with latest 20.8 jar as well but its giving same output.
For example ppt file has name designSlide.pptx then I get Microsoft_PowerPoint_Presentation71.pptx

Comment: you may post your issue with attachments (source file(s)) in Aspose forums as requested.